# Django - Authentication using only a password

Tags: django

I need to implement authentication using only a password.

I know that for security reasons this is not recommended, but I need this approach because it logs in using only RFID codes. I could treat this code as a regular field (not a password) and just retrieve the user with this code, but I want to hash this value so I iterate through all users using check_password.

[models.py]

```
class CustomUserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, password=None, **extra_fields):
        user = self.model(**extra_fields)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, password=None, **extra_fields):
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff', True)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', True)

        if extra_fields.get('is_staff') is not True:
            raise ValueError('Superuser must have is_staff=True.')
        if extra_fields.get('is_superuser') is not True:
            raise ValueError('Superuser must have is_superuser=True.')
        
        return self.create_user(**extra_fields)

class CustomUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True, null=True)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=40, unique=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    objects = CustomUserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username
    
    @property
    def full_name(self):
        return f'{self.first_name} {self.last_name}'
```

[views.py]

```
def login_view(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect(reverse('home'))
    
    if request.method == 'POST':
        password = request.POST.get('rfid_code')
        user = authenticate(request, password=password)
        if user is not None:
            login(request, user)
            return redirect(settings.LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL)
    
    return render(request, 'account/login.html')
```

[backend.py]

```
class CustomAuthenticationBackend(BaseBackend):

    def authenticate(self, request, password=None):
        try:
            User = get_user_model()
            for user in User.objects.all():
                # this method returns False even if the password is correct
                if user.check_password(password): 
                    return user
                else:
                    raise User.DoesNotExist('User does not exist')

        except CustomUser.DoesNotExist:
            return None

    def get_user(self, user_id):
        try:
            return CustomUser.objects.get(pk=user_id)
        except CustomUser.DoesNotExist:
            return None
```

Why authentication doesn't work?

Comment: Why not see the first *n* bytes of the RFID as username, and the remaining as password?

Comment: Why do you want to hash the RFID contents if it is the only identifier you have for a user? Iterating over all of the users and checking each of the hashes isn't a very efficient method. Although I've never worked with RFIDs I'd try to draw parallels with JWT. Try to store some signature along with the user ID, etc. It should be possible to fit this into RFID tags since ones around 1-2 KB exist. In the database store only the user ID and validate the authenticity using the signature.

Comment: Note the obvious concern with your strategy is that people can read and hence copy RFIDs without your users knowing it.

Comment: Could you write the code for how you create new users. There is possibly something wrong with that.

Comment: Thank you for your help. When setting rfid_code as a password, I set the username based on the last three digits. When calling the authenticate method, it passes the password and catches the user with it, and then I successfully authenticate.
It is enough for me. I know it's not very secure, but the system will be locked to VPN, so that's enough.
Thanks again users